# Weird lag like phenomenon by gaming with stable low ping

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

I have stable connection, low ping and low jitter. Still with a game with Q3 engine I got some kind of weird lag. Bullets on my screen arrive 1 sec later than they should be. So for example I go to cover and I still got hit by enemy bullets fired 1 sec before. I have been trying to debug this issue for many years without success. When it started I changed too many things the same time: my entire PC, my OP system, even my ISP, so I am not sure which component causes it. I managed to rule out many suspects in the past years, but the list is still not empty, so I continue with my internet connection. I managed to find a bad coaxial cable with the modem status info a few years before, so I know that it can be very useful to debug internet connection, I just don't have the experience to use it, so I am looking for an expert in the topic. Can you tell from modem status info whether the connection is ok?

Downstream bonded channels

```
Channel     Frequency (Hz)  Power (dBmV)    SNR (dB)    Modulation      Channel ID
1           434000000       0               36          256qam          11
2           362000000       1               35          256qam          2
3           370000000       1               35          256qam          3
4           378000000       1               35          256qam          4
5           386000000       2               36          256qam          5
6           394000000       2               37          256qam          6
7           402000000       2               36          256qam          7
8           410000000       1               35          256qam          8
9           418000000       0               35          256qam          9
10          426000000       0               36          256qam          10
11          354000000       1               35          256qam          1
12          442000000       0               35          256qam          12
13          450000000       0               36          256qam          13
14          458000000       0               36          256qam          14
15          466000000       0               36          256qam          15
```

Downstream bonded channels

```
Channel     Locked Status   RxMER (dB)  Pre RS Errors   Post RS Errors
1           Locked          36.610      36761070506     3117
2           Locked          35.595      36759588651     5176
3           Locked          35.780      36759584906     2301
4           Locked          35.595      36759581385     6047
5           Locked          36.387      36759591605     826
6           Locked          37.356      36759594494     1162
7           Locked          36.610      36759586816     1211
8           Locked          35.780      36759593878     2577
9           Locked          35.780      36759587225     3299
10          Locked          36.387      36759594403     2757
11          Locked          35.595      36759574706     10942
12          Locked          35.780      36759589017     5860
13          Locked          36.387      36759593408     2670
14          Locked          36.387      36759597344     2373
15          Locked          36.610      36759579432     18079
```

Upstream bonded channels

```
Channel     Frequency (Hz)  Power (dBmV)    Symbol Rate (ksps)  Modulation  Channel ID
1           30600000        46              5.120               64qam       1
2           59800000        46              5.120               64qam       5
3           52400000        46              5.120               64qam       4
4           37200000        45              5.120               64qam       2
5           45000000        46              5.120               64qam       3
```

Upstream bonded channels

```
Channel     Channel Type    T1 Timeouts     T2 Timeouts     T3 Timeouts     T4 Timeouts 
1           2.0             0               0               24              0
2           2.0             0               0               12              0
3           2.0             0               0               36              0
4           2.0             0               0               19              0
5           2.0             0               0               22              0
```

Network Log

```
Time                    Priority    Description
20-05-2018 21:49:19     error       DHCP RENEW WARNING - Field invalid in response v4 option;CM-MAC={mac-1};CMTS-MAC={mac-2};CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
20-05-2018 11:55:55     critical    No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC={mac-1};CMTS-MAC={mac-2};CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
20-05-2018 09:49:19     error       DHCP RENEW WARNING - Field invalid in response v4 option;CM-MAC={mac-1};CMTS-MAC={mac-2};CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
20-05-2018 09:06:16     critical    No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC={mac-1};CMTS-MAC={mac-2};CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
19-05-2018 21:49:18     error       DHCP RENEW WARNING - Field invalid in response v4 option;CM-MAC={mac-1};CMTS-MAC={mac-2};CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
19-05-2018 16:00:33     critical    No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC={mac-1};CMTS-MAC={mac-2};CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
```

Comment: If you have changed *everything* except the game and the problem persists, then perhaps the problem is with the game itself. Some games just have very poor networking and depending on how a mod is written it could potentially make things a lot worse.

Comment: @Mokubai Well I played the same game from 2004 to 2010 without any issues. I asked other players too, almost nobody has problems with it. I read some old topics like this with the same issue: http://forums.warchest.com/showthread.php/13930-Need-help-with-bullet-lag-in-ET But it appears to be something very rare.

Comment: Doesn't really mean much. The game engine could be tuned for high latency 56k modem connections and rejects data that comes "too fast". Or it could be that other players are hacking. If your connection is stable and has nearly zero packet loss then chances are it is either the server you are connecting to or your game software that is the problem. What is the server ping?

Comment: @Mokubai I had ADSL on phone lines before, now I got UPC internet on coaxial cable. My experience that the second one is a lot more reliable. I am not sure what the "reject data that comes too fast" means, but I doubt I am the only one playing this game with a "fast" internet connection. Others are not hacking. Ping is around 50. There are still some high skilled players around having similar stats I had before 2010 (when I changed everything). So I guess if the servers are ok for them, then it is not a server issue.

Comment: @Mokubai The game itself did not change much since 2007. No new patches. Only the mod I am playing with changed somewhat, but that should not affect the basics like connection, rendering, etc... What I know of that it cannot handle is more than 1200 DPI and 500 Hz by mice (it causes negative mouse accel), so I set mine to those values. The high speed connection should not be a problem, it is a game from 2003.